# Is it possible to create ClickOnce-like functionality for an Excel 2003 addin?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, clickonce, excel-2003, office-2003

I'm working on an Excel 2003 addin (users will upgrade to newer Office, but not any time soon), and am wanting to use functionality to automatically check for a newer version, and deploy it if there is one.

I can't use ClickOnce as that is Office 2007 (so VSTO v3) or better.

I'd like to have some functionality that does this kind of task though.

Also, I'm aware you can deploy applications using Group Policy, but that has caused a number of issues in the past, so the user isn't keen on that.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you can get something like App Life http://www.kineticjump.com/update/ to work with the addin. Which I've successfully used, but never with an office addin. I think you're stuck with deployment using Group Policy.